# É mais rápido usar a função "Pow()" ou fazer multiplicações?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, matemática

Se eu usar uma função `pow()` do C ou C++ será sempre mais lento que fazer a multiplicação do valor a quantidade de vezes do expoente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca dá para afirmar algo sem o caso concreto. Até porque a implementação pode fazer algo específico que pode mudar a percepção inicial que alguém pode ter.

Principalmente em C++ pode ser possível existir implementações mais específicas para alguns casos, embora até onde em sei, não tem. É possível até que seja transformando em multiplicação. É possível usar alguma fórmula específica para alguns casos que ele sabe que pode chegar em algum resultado de forma mais simples, pode até usar *bit shift*. Enfim muita otimização pode ser feita. Nunca considere que testando uma situação tem um resultado.

Vou considerar que o expoente é sempre inteiro e por isso pode multiplicar uma quantidade de vezes de forma simples, se o valor tiver parte decimal, aí a multiplicação pode ser tornar mais complexa, pode ser até mais difícil acertar, não só começa ter chance de ser mais lenta.

E aí começa a explicação que a função tem que tratar de muitas situações diferentes e deve ser mais complicado otimizar, especialmente em C. A multiplicação vai direto ao ponto. E o compilador pode ter mais informação do que pode otimizar ali na hora do que a função.

Então pelo menos para poucas multiplicações a multiplicação deve ser mais rápido ou pelo menos igual em todas as situações. Se tiver que fazer muitas multiplicações ainda tende ser mais rápido ou igual, mas começa dar margem para obter alguns atalhos.

Se for importante tem que medir para o caso concreto.

Comment: tem como medir essa diferença? medir o tempo de execução da função pow() e programar direto ?

Comment: Sim, claro, é possível com casos concretos. O erro pode ser medir algo genérico e achar que sempre será daquele jeito.

Answer (score 3):

Comumente consumida em **C** quanto no  **C++** a função `pow()`  é demasiadamente otimizada pelos compiladores, para melhor desempenho em tempo de execução, avisando que a implementação pode variar entre os compiladores.

Compiladores usam exponenciação binária (*é um [algoritmo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divis%C3%A3o_e_conquista) de divisão e conquista*) por ser mais eficaz em expoente com valores altos.

Entre as implementações inclui a metodologia  série de [Taylor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Taylor) é a aproximação polinomial de uma função. (*valor da base elevada ao expoente inteiro*).

Essa é uma ilustra de uma implementação simples usando **C++** (*cplusplus*).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

double pow(double x, double y) {
    double resultado = 1.0;
    while (y > 0) {
        resultado *= x;
        y--;
    }
    return resultado;
}

int main() {
    double x = 2.0;
    double y = 450000000.0; 

    clock_t inicio = clock();
    double resultado = pow(x, y);
    clock_t fim = clock();

    cout << "Resultado do calculo: " << resultado;
    cout << "Tempo de execução: " << ((double)(fim - inicio) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " segundos";

    return 0;
}
```

Quanto maior for valor de **y**  mais pesado e custoso será o cálculo

Segui o código usando a função `pow()` em **C++**

```
double x = 2.0;
double y = 450000000.0; 


clock_t inicio = clock();

double resultado = std::pow(x, y);

clock_t fim = clock();
double duracao = double(fim - inicio) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout << "Resultado do calculo: " << resultado;
cout << "\nTempo de execução: " << duracao << " segundos";
```

Através de teste e estudo,  quando o valor do expoente for baixo note que o comportamento da função `pow()` é análogo a uma multiplicação direta mas quando o  expoente é maior é mais rápida do que programar diretamente.

Foi usado o **g++ compiler** dando o resultado de *3e-05 segundos* (3 x 10 elevado a -5  = 0.00003 )
Como podem observar e contastar sim **"** *Nunca dá para afirmar algo sem o caso concreto. Até porque a implementação pode fazer algo específico que pode mudar a percepção inicial ...* **"**